# How to translate undefined strings with PySide

Tags: internationalization, pyside6

About the process of internationalization with PySide.

The problem is the translation of dynamic variables.

For example:

```
self.tr("Saved %1 in file %2").arg(datetime).arg(filename)
```

This can be used because of PyQt.

And `QTranslator` doesn't keep up with format.

For example:

```
self.tr("Saved %s in file %s" % (datetime, filename))
```

They say that this is a bad way for QTranslator.

How to do the same thing with PySide?

**Environment**

Python3.10.8 PySide6.4

Comment: Well, that is quite obvious: it cannot "keep up with escape sequence", because the argument is already an "unescaped" sequence (btw, the term is wrong, as *escaping* is a completely different matter): the argument of `tr()` has been already formatted when you call the function. If you need advanced string formatting, you need to provide a different function that formats the given text before calling the translation function, otherwise update the translation with a higher level translation procedure.

Comment: Oh, I mistook the word. Not escape sequence, but format.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact: calling `tr()` with a given string will not update the widgets based on an eventually new locale. If you want to change the result based on a different locale, then you have to call it again. Strings are immutable (nor are the properties that depend on them), they are not changed dynamically.

Comment: I'm taking a process of internationalization, and I could partially do the dynamic translation now. But in the case which I must use format string, %s, %s or f"{}", I cannot find the solution. If it is a static translation, there is no problem. The translation is confirmed at the executing of the application.

Comment: Internationalization is a painful matter. Developers have been struggling with it for *decades*. Whenever you need dynamical string localization, it means that you have to dynamically call the functions that *localize* the content of that string(s). You cannot "statically" set a string value that could potentially change during runtime: that displayed value must be recalled dynamically based on the locale, which means that you need to understand how and when that string is get or shown, and decide how and/or when alter it.

Comment: Yes, yes, I understand what you are talking about. I must find a point of compromise between qm file and hard-code programming?

Comment: Yes. You have to find the best compromise for your needs. Unfortunately, we cannot help you with that, because internationalization is such a complex matter that its implementation always depends on single cases. Depending on your needs, you might need even more complex "sub-levels" of string abstractions and related implementations. There is no easy way to do it: if you need custom representation, it always depends on how the program is implemented, meaning that you need to find your own way.